# How to create a login form - OOP in Java?

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, system, inventory

I already have a inventory system which accesses a certain table on a certain database.

Now I want to create a new frame that will serve as a login form before the user can proceed to the main inventory system frame.

I want it to access the same database but different table, (ex. user_table and item_table under the inventory_system_db database).

If the user logged on an admin account then he can access the inventory system with admin controls (ex. edit, add, delete).

And when he logged on as a normal user he will be able to access the inventory system but without admin controls.

Things I want to know:

- How to create a login form?
- How to make it proceed to inventory system?

Comment: That's a much too vague question. Try doing something, and come back with your code and a precise question if you're stuck. You'll need a JDialog, a JTextField and a JPasswordField.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a Login Dialog just check the code below.

```
 public class LoginPane extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
  String itsUsername = "";
  String itsPassword = "";
  boolean itsFirst = true;
  boolean itsKeep = false;
  JTextField itsUserField = new JTextField(15);
  JPasswordField itsPassField = new JPasswordField(15);
  JCheckBox itsKeepBox = new JCheckBox("Save details:", false);
  boolean itsInit = false;

  public LoginPane() {
    super();
setTitle("Login");
setModal(true);
getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Username:"));
getContentPane().add(itsUserField);
getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Password"));
getContentPane().add(itsPassField);
getContentPane().add(itsKeepBox);
JButton submit = new JButton("done");
getContentPane().add(submit);
submit.addActionListener(this);
pack();
 }

public String[] getLogin() {
if (!itsKeep && !itsFirst) {
  return null;
}
if (!itsInit) {
  return null;
}
itsFirst = false;
String[] res = new String[2];
res[0] = itsUsername;
res[1] = itsPassword;
if (!itsKeep) {
  itsUsername = "";
  itsPassword = "";
}
return res;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
itsUsername = itsUserField.getText();
itsPassword = new String(itsPassField.getPassword());
itsKeep = itsKeepBox.isSelected();
itsInit = true;
setVisible(false);
}
}
```

You can add action for button as you wish!

Answer (score 0):

There can be many solutions to solve this but one of them is:

1. In the users table in data, store the user's privileges.
2. On login, check for the privileges and if it's Admin (or whatever you call it0, grant him the right to add, delete and any of the permissions, otherwise restrict him doing so.
3. To adhere this, you must have to put checks on all of these permissions that whether a user has permission to do this task or not.
4. Also, you can hide the Add, Delete (if these are in the form of buttons) if user is not permitted to perform actions.

So, all of this depends upon the architecture of your application.